# How to write values to excel from get method using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am very new to python, and i trying to read data from json through URL using get method and search few parameters in json based on filters and the output is printed. I am trying to put the printed values to excel which i need help with? Can someone help me with this

```
def get_info():
args = 'draft'
offers = get_offer(args).json()
for offer in offers:
if offer['createdBy'] == 'tom':
    print("ID::" +id['id'])
    print("Value::" +name['createdBy'])
get_info()
```

this get info method print me values.
I want these values to be put in xlsx. I tried the below but looks like something is incorrect. - `offerFrame.to_excel('/Users/tom/Python/testoutput.xlsx')`

can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is problem with `offerFrame.to_excel('/Users/tom/Python/testoutput.xlsx')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offerFrame` is never created, so that's probably why `to_excel` doesn't work. Try this example:

```py
import pandas
import requests

# Don't know what your function looks like, but I'll use this one
def get_offer(args) -> requests.Response:
    return requests.get(f"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")


def get_info() -> pandas.DataFrame:

    # Get some data
    args = "draft"
    offers = get_offer(args).json()

    # Convert the data to a dataframe
    offerFrame = pandas.DataFrame(offers)
    return offerFrame


offerFrame = get_info()
offerFrame.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: def get_info():
    args = 'draft'
    offers = get_offer(args).json()
    for offer in offers:
        if offer['pCode'] == 'TXT':
            for obj in offer['MapValue']:
                print("ID::" +offer['id'])
                print("Created by::" +offer['createdBy'])
                print("Country::" +obj['country'])
                print("Code::" +offer['pCode'])
                offerFrame = pd.DataFrame(offer, obj)
                return offerFrame
offerFrame = get_info()
offerFrame.to_excel("outputtest1038excel.xlsx")
I need output of these print to xls. How do i do it?

Comment: Thanks soo much, this worked. Now i have one more question if i need to include a logic to extract particular data like below, how do i do it? I have pasted my code above. Can you please help? How to do if we have to write to excel from every for loop of if loop. I want to print in excel every print statement i have written in code

Comment: Not really sure what you want here... One Excel file with sheets, or a bunch of Excel files, or just one Excel file? Also, should every print statement be a cell, or should it be the title of the file, or....

Comment: I used dataframes and i was able to get it. Thanks